# Why does this type annotation make my functional dependency conflict go away? (and why does it only happen on some versions of GHC?)

Tags: haskell, ghc, functional-dependencies, state-monad

So I've been playing around with `MonadState` class and I have encountered something I consider very strange.

I can try to write a monad like the following:

```
test ::
  ( MonadState Int m
  , MonadState Bool m
  )
    => m ()
test = do
  ((+1) <$> get) >>= put 
  (not  <$> get) >>= put
```

If we compile this in ghc 8.6.4 we get the following:

```
MonadTrans.hs:10:13: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘Bool’
        arising from a functional dependency between constraints:
          ‘MonadState Bool m’
            arising from a use of ‘get’ at MonadTrans.hs:10:13-15
          ‘MonadState Int m’
            arising from the type signature for:
                           test :: forall (m :: * -> *).
                                   (MonadState Int m, MonadState Bool m) =>
                                   m ()
            at MonadTrans.hs:(4,1)-(8,11)
    • In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘get’
      In the first argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘((+ 1) <$> get)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: ((+ 1) <$> get) >>= put
   |
10 |   ((+1) <$> get) >>= put
   |
```

(older versions of GHC for example [8.2.2](https://tio.run/##ZY29CsIwFEb3PsUHdWjQFlzFdrAgFBQHnyDSSy3mpzS3UBCfPSaZBIc7fOfAuU/pXqSUf5c5LtIMixwIZ0Xr@FDUWsO0skNefrJRT3ZmRDZbVV2tkX11Z8lUtUo655kc43DIgALJJonOMHSAu194slYlKsIBdQONQmQpUaO3MVJs9wLHTYOBWKBpakwLIxpjGX/Gazma8B/dLabSimKmMP0X) are actually fine with this and compile.  I have no idea why.)

Ok this makes sense since the declaration of `MonadState` has a dependency in it:

```
class Monad m => MonadState s m | m -> s where
```

we cannot have a single Monad be both `MonadState Int` and `MonadState Bool`.  But here is where things get a little strange.

If I add a type annotation the code will compile

```
test ::
  ( MonadState Int m
  , MonadState Bool m
  )
    => m ()
test = do
  (((+1) :: Int -> Int) <$> get) >>= put
  (not  <$> get) >>= put
```

To me this seems very strange.  A moment ago it was complaining about a very real functional dependency conflict between the two.  I don't see how disambiguating the type of `(+1)` makes that conflict go away.

What is happening here?  How does the second one compile while the first fails?  And why does the first compile on 8.2.2?

Comment: You might be interested in the [effect-stack](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/effect-stack) package I recently released. (Mostly for funsies, but if somebody finds it useful so much the better...)

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks!  I had no idea this package existed and is very closely related to what lead me to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
plus1 :: Int -> Int
plus1 = (+ 1)

test :: (MonadState Int m, MonadState Bool m) => m ()
test = do
    (plus1 <$> get) >>= put
    (not <$> get) >>= put
```

Compiles fine, even without the inline type annotation.
What the functor?!

The thing is, when the compiler complains in your first example, it doesn't complain about the type signature just because it decided to verify it for the heck of it. Look a bit further in the error message: `...In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘get’...`

Aha! The source of trouble is actually `get`! But why?

The trouble is the bloody overloaded arithmetic. You see, operator `(+)` has a polymorphic type, like this:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

And naked literals also have similar type:

```
1 :: Num a => a
```

So when you write `(+1)`, it doesn't let the compiler know that you meant `Int`. It admits any type `a` as long as there is `Num a`.

So the compiler turns to further surroundings to get the type. But wait! Further surroundings are also generic:

```
get :: MonadState a m => m a
put :: MonadState a m => a -> m ()
```

Ok, so maybe we can get the type from the signature of `test`? Let's check that! Oh, no, the signature actually contains a conflict! Bail, bail, bail! That's when you get the error.

All of this doesn't happen on the second line, because `not` has a non-polymorphic type `not :: Bool -> Bool`, so the required type of `get` is known. And this is why either giving an inline type annotation `Int -> Int` or having it come from an external function `plus1` helps on the first line as well.

If you do provide enough type information for the values in the body, the compiler never has to analyze the `test` signature. The signature specifies that there should be a `MonadState Int m` dictionary, and that's good enough. Whoever calls the function will have provide the dictionary, and we'll just use that.

Now, of course, when you get around to *calling* this function, you'll need to provide both dictionaries `MonadState Int m` and `MonadState Bool m`, and you can't get those, so you can't actually call such function. But you sure can define it.

---

That being said, you *CAN* actually have a monad with two different `MonadState` instances if you're willing to be sneaky enough about it.

Of course, if you try it straight up, you get a very straight up error:

```
data M a = M
instance MonadState Int M
instance MonadState Bool M

> Functional dependencies conflict between instance declarations:
>       instance MonadState Int M -- Defined at ...
>       instance MonadState Bool M -- Defined at ...
```

Ok, let's start small:

```
data M a = M
instance MonadState Int M

> Illegal instance declaration for `MonadState a M'
>     The liberal coverage condition fails in class `MonadState'
>       for functional dependency: `m -> s'
>     Reason: lhs type `M' does not determine rhs type `a'
>     Un-determined variable: a
```

Alright, so *something* in the type of `M` must indicate the type `Int`. That makes sense. Let's add it:

```
data M x a = M a
instance MonadState Int (M Int)
```

Ok, this works. So far so good.
But of course, in order to define `MonadState Bool`, I need to add `Bool` to the type as well:

```
data M x y a = M a
instance MonadState Int (M Int y)
instance MonadState Bool (M x Bool)

> Functional dependencies conflict between instance declarations:
```

Ah, still fundep failure! Ok, well, that makes sense too.

So is there a way I can fool the compiler into not checking the instances for the fundep? Yes, there is! I can be sneaky and make the instances overlapped, like this:

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (Num a, Show a) => MonadState a (M a y) where
    get = M 42
    put x = M ()

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} MonadState Bool (M x Bool) where
    get = M True
    put x = M ()
```

Now all that's left is the `Monad` instance, and we can have it all actually run:

```
data M x y a = M a deriving (Functor, Show)

instance Applicative (M x y) where
    pure = M
    (M f) <*> (M x) = M $ f x

instance Monad (M x y) where
    (M x) >>= f = f x

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (Num a, Show a) => MonadState a (M a y) where
    get = M 42
    put x = trace ("Setting Num: " ++ show x) $ M ()

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} MonadState Bool (M x Bool) where
    get = M True
    put x = trace ("Setting Bool: " ++ show x) $ M ()

g :: M Int Bool ()
g = test

main = print g
```

I've included debug trace to verify how they're actually going to work, so the above program prints:

```
Setting Num: 43    
Setting Bool: False
M ()
```

Comment: I am very suspicious of your explanation since it would equally apply pretty much any version of GHC, while the problem is not present in every version of GHC.  Could you provide some evidence to substantiate your narrative?

Comment: Also I find the sentence "Compiles fine, even without the type annotation." to be a little weird.  The type annotation is still there, and if we remove it it stops compiling.

Comment: Fair enough to be 'cautious' about the explanation. One difference might be down to defaulting rules (which did change a little while ago, not sure which exact version). Are you entering some of this code at the command line? Or is it all in proper compiled modules?